# Custom picture placed in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way to create a custom image, and then place it into a layout you have?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

Example xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_image"/>
```

Then you would just stick `my_image.png` into `res/drawable`.

**Edit** - to draw dynamically you want to subclass `View` and override [onDraw(Canvas)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) with a custom drawing method.

The other option is to load multiple images into `res/drawable` and choose between them in your Java code:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setBitmapResource(R.id.some_image);
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I needed to be more clear though. I need to draw a custom image based on user input and then place it into a layout like you have above

Answer (score 0):

Just what Matthew said. Also if you meant to place the image as the layout background you can do it like

```
<android:background="@drawable/background">
```

where "background" is an image like background.png placed in the res/drawable folder.